# How to build 64 bit version of Oracle OCI static libraries (libocia/w/m.a) for MIGW using Code blocks?

Tags: c++, oracle, gcc, oracle-call-interface, mingw-w64

Does anyone know how to build 64 bit versions of Oracle OCI static libraries?

I downloaded ocilib-3.12.1-windows.zip (2.9 MB) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/orclib/files/

Got this ocilib_static_lib_mingw.cbp project under /proj folder. It compiles fine under Migw GCC 32 bit. But, it doesn't compile under 64 bit Migw GCC 64 bit.

```
-------------- Build: Release - ANSI in ocilib_static_lib_mingw (compiler: Mingw/TDM 64)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -O2 -Wall -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI -DOCI_IMPORT_RUNTIME -DOCI_API=__stdcall -IC:\ocilib\include -c C:\ocilib\src\agent.c -o obj\Release\src\agent.o
In file included from C:\ocilib\src\oci_defs.h:58:0,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\oci_api.h:58,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\oci_import.h:63,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\ocilib_defs.h:39,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\ocilib_types.h:38,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\ocilib_internal.h:38,
                 from C:\ocilib\src\agent.c:35:
C:\ocilib\src\oci_types.h:253:25: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ubig_ora'
 typedef unsigned _int64 ubig_ora;
                         ^
C:\ocilib\src\oci_types.h:254:25: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'sbig_ora'
 typedef   signed _int64 sbig_ora;
```

C:\ocilib\src\oci_types.h

```
#ifdef _WIN64

  #ifndef lint
253: typedef unsigned _int64 ubig_ora;
254: typedef   signed _int64 sbig_ora;
  #else
    #define ubig_ora unsigned _int64
    #define sbig_ora signed _int64
  #endif
```

I have no clue about "expected '=' ..." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like Windows platform was detected and therefore it's assumed that MSVC compiler is used. Older MSVC versions did not support typedefs like int64_t (but they had their own versions INT64 or _int64). Since your project is pure C (no C++)

Do something like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN64

# if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   ifndef lint
typedef unsigned _int64 ubig_ora;
typedef   signed _int64 sbig_ora;
#   else
#   define ubig_ora unsigned _int64
#   define sbig_ora signed _int64
#   endif
# elif defined(__MINGW64__)    
#   include <stdint.h>
typedef uint64_t ubig_ora;
typedef int64_t sbig_ora;
# endif

...
```

~